# Google Analytics for Facebook Applications - use http:// or https://

Tags: facebook, google-analytics

I'm putting analytics on a facebook application and i'm unsure what the protocol would be.

**Here's a screenshot from the analytics set up**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In general I would prefer https. No idea what google does with it but https is the best way to share your application and its contents. If you run your App in a facebook iframe tab your app has to be reachable via https. That means that the content also gets shared via https (because FB will call your app by the users privacy settings (http or https)).
So all my apps and their sharing URLs are set to https so that the like-count etc. are the same and are reachable whether called via FB or not. Because of this I would prefer the https way.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook now requires https for all applications, so I don't see any reason not to use https for your analytics script.

However, if you use a protocol-less url, your browser will figure out for you. E.g.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//www.google.com/yourscript.js'></script>
```